# parse_ini_file failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php

I've been trying to load a page and this error shows up.

> Warning: parse_ini_file(C:/wamp64/www/../private/sampleapp2.ini):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   C:\wamp64\www\sampleapp2\dao\ConnectionManager.php on line 6
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access
>   denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO) in
>   C:\wamp64\www\sampleapp2\dao\ConnectionManager.php:8 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\wamp64\www\sampleapp2\dao\ConnectionManager.php(8):
>   PDO->__construct('mysql:host=;dbn...', NULL, NULL) #1
>   C:\wamp64\www\sampleapp2\dao\WarehouseDAO.php(7):
>   ConnectionManager->getConnection() #2
>   C:\wamp64\www\sampleapp2\index.php(25): WarehouseDAO->getAll() #3
>   {main} thrown in C:\wamp64\www\sampleapp2\dao\ConnectionManager.php on
>   line 8

---

The parse_ini_file is sampleapp2.ini. It is placed in C:\wamp64\www\private (it is one of the requirements of the question I am working on).

```
host=localhost
username=root
password=
dbname=sampleapp2
```

---

The rest ofthe files are placed in C:\wamp64\www\sampleapp2 with 2 subfolders, model and dao. The connection manager is placed in the dao folder.

It stated that the error is in line 6 of the connection manager. ($config = parse_ini_file....)

```
<?php

class ConnectionManager {
# Return a new PDO object by reading information from sampleapp2.ini file
public function getConnection() {    
    $config = parse_ini_file($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/../private/sampleapp2.ini'); 
    $url  = "mysql:host={$config['host']};dbname={$config['dbname']}";
    return new PDO($url, $config['username'], $config['password']);
    }
}

?>
```

I checked mySQL and the database name is the same as the ini file so I am not 
sure what is wrong. Thanks!

Comment: It seems like the `private` folder is inside the www-folder, while you're trying to fetch it from outside the www-folder. _"It is placed in C:\wamp64\www\private"_ and the error states _"C:/wamp64/www/../private/sampleapp2.ini"_. You should probably move the `private` folder to be next to the www-folder instead of in it (up one level). You don't want the ini-file to be directly accessed from the web.

Answer (score 0):

The error suggests that PHP is looking for the file here:

```
C:/wamp64/www/../private/sampleapp2.ini
```

Which equals to:

```
C:/wamp64/private/sampleapp2.ini
```

You say that you've placed the .ini file here:

```
C:/wamp64/www/private/sampleapp2.ini
```

Which is not the same. Move the file up one folder and it should be fine.